# Code to display binary value from 1 hall sensor A3144 connected with shift register 74HC165 when magnet is brought near to it or taken away?

Tags: arduino-ide

[image]

I have checked my connections and when I bring a magnet close to the hall sensors the voltage on them which is apprx. 4.5V becomes 0V and when I remove the magnet the sensor turns back to 4.5V. This means that all the hall sensors are responding to the magnets which makes my connections alright. I want to get 0 when magnet is brought closer to the sensor and 1 when taken away.

The below code shows 11111111 continuously and does not get affected even if magnet is brought close or taken away. I expected the code to show 00000000 until magnet is brought closer to any sensor. If magnet is brought closer to 1st sensor, it should have shown 10000000 and so forth.

```
int load = 7;
int clockEnablePin = 4;
int dataIn = 5;
int clockIn = 6;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(load, OUTPUT);
pinMode(clockEnablePin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(clockIn, OUTPUT);
pinMode(dataIn, INPUT);
digitalWrite(clockEnablePin, LOW);
digitalWrite(clockIn, LOW);
}

void loop() {

//Write pulse to load pin
digitalWrite(load, LOW);
digitalWrite(load, HIGH);

//Get data from 74HC165
byte incoming = shiftIn(dataIn, clockIn, LSBFIRST);

// Print to serial monitor
Serial.print("Pin States: \r\n");
Serial.println(incoming, BIN);
delay(200);
}

uint8_t shiftIn(uint8_t dataIn, uint8_t clockIn, uint8_t bitOrder) {
uint8_t value = 0;
uint8_t i;
for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
 digitalWrite(clockIn, HIGH);
 if (bitOrder == LSBFIRST)
 {
  value |= digitalRead(dataIn) << i;
 }
 else
 {
  value |= digitalRead(dataIn) << (7 - i);
 }
 digitalWrite(clockIn, LOW);
}
return value;
}
```

---

The code as well as the schematic is correct. The problem was with shift register. Thank you everyone for your suggestions.

Comment: The wiring seems good to me. The code seems to be from [here](https://dronebotworkshop.com/shift-registers/), which I used before myself (though I have the clock inhibit pin hardwired). Does it work when you test the shift register without the sensors but with buttons or wires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connections are correct in the above diagram. I have had a terrible experience with non working shift register. Some 74HC165 don't work properly(might be duplicate). So, try buying from a verified store.

Use this code to get HIGH or LOW value as output. You can change them to 1 or 0 as per your requirement.

I used this code and it works perfect with 8 Hall switches connected to one shift register 74HC165. Don't forget to connect your pins with your Arduino Uno as depicted in the code or you can update your code as per your connections of shift register with Arduino Uno. You can increase the number of inputs by adding more shift register 74HC165 to the circuit & also you just need to update the value of number of shift chips in the below code.

```
/* How many shift register chips are daisy-chained.
*/
#define NUMBER_OF_SHIFT_CHIPS   1

/* Width of data (how many ext lines).
*/
#define DATA_WIDTH   NUMBER_OF_SHIFT_CHIPS * 8

/* Width of pulse to trigger the shift register to read and latch.
*/
#define PULSE_WIDTH_USEC   5

/* Optional delay between shift register reads.
*/
#define POLL_DELAY_MSEC   1

/* You will need to change the "int" to "long" If the
 * NUMBER_OF_SHIFT_CHIPS is higher than 2.
*/
#define BYTES_VAL_T unsigned int

int ploadPin        = 7;  // Connects to Parallel load pin the 165
int clockEnablePin  = 4;  // Connects to Clock Enable pin the 165
int dataPin         = 5; // Connects to the Q7 pin the 165
int clockPin        = 6; // Connects to the Clock pin the 165


BYTES_VAL_T pinValues;
BYTES_VAL_T oldPinValues;

/* This function is essentially a "shift-in" routine reading the
 * serial Data from the shift register chips and representing
 * the state of those pins in an unsigned integer (or long).
*/
BYTES_VAL_T read_shift_regs()
{
    long bitVal;
    BYTES_VAL_T bytesVal = 0;

    /* Trigger a parallel Load to latch the state of the data lines,
    */
    digitalWrite(clockEnablePin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ploadPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(PULSE_WIDTH_USEC);
    digitalWrite(ploadPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(clockEnablePin, LOW);

    /* Loop to read each bit value from the serial out line
     * of the SN74HC165N.
    */
    for(int i = 0; i < DATA_WIDTH; i++)
    {
        bitVal = digitalRead(dataPin);

        /* Set the corresponding bit in bytesVal.
        */
        bytesVal |= (bitVal << ((DATA_WIDTH-1) - i));

        /* Pulse the Clock (rising edge shifts the next bit).
        */
        digitalWrite(clockPin, HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(PULSE_WIDTH_USEC);
        digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW);
    }

    return(bytesVal);
}

/* Dump the list of zones along with their current status.
*/
void display_pin_values()
{
    Serial.print("Pin States:\r\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < DATA_WIDTH; i++)
    {
        Serial.print("  Pin-");
        Serial.print(i);
        Serial.print(": ");

        if((pinValues >> i) & 1)
            Serial.print("HIGH");
        else
            Serial.print("LOW");

        Serial.print("\r\n");
    }

    Serial.print("\r\n");
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    /* Initialize our digital pins...
    */
    pinMode(ploadPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(clockEnablePin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(dataPin, INPUT);

    digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ploadPin, HIGH);

    /* Read in and display the pin states at startup.
    */
    pinValues = read_shift_regs();
    display_pin_values();
    oldPinValues = pinValues;
}

void loop()
{
    /* Read the state of all zones.
    */
    pinValues = read_shift_regs();

    /* If there was a chage in state, display which ones changed.
    */
    if(pinValues != oldPinValues)
    {
        Serial.print("*Pin value change detected*\r\n");
        display_pin_values();
        oldPinValues = pinValues;
    }

    delay(POLL_DELAY_MSEC);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Preset your clockIn and clockEnablePin pins to LOW in the setup function. Do not manipulate them in the loop function. You do not need to use the delayMicroseconds() functions because the 74HC165 is a great deal faster than Arduino read/write functions.

Comment: You might want to write your own shiftin() function since the QH needs to be sampled before the first clock pulse.